# Will having PHP app and MySQL on two servers, connecting via Internet be an issue?

Tags: networking

I am planning to migrate a Wordpress site to two virtual servers on Cloudways. It's a relatively busy site (around 500,000 visitors a week), so I wanted to split the application (& caching, etc.) on one Vultr instance, and have MySQL on another.

Normally, I'd have the two talking to each other over a local network, with the MySQL server removed from the DMZ. As they would be on the same network, latency would be minimal.

However, Cloudways don't accomodate deploying in that way. So the two servers will have to talk over a public IP. They will not be on the same local network. Although they will be in the same datacenter location.

I realise this potentially exposes the MySQL server to the Internet, when normally I'd want to keep it unexposed.

I'd like to have some input on whether this set up is:

1) Likely to have too much latency, and thus defeat the purpose of splitting the App and DB onto separate servers (i.e., to get performance gains).

2) Whether this presents any significant security concern. I presume we can set up the firewall on the MySQL server to only allow connections from the IP address of the Application (Wordpress) server. Correct? And that should minimise the security risk.

Having not set things up in this way before, I am wanting to run this past people with greater experience than myself, to make sure I'm not over looking potential issues.

Comment: You use TLS on your database connection, or else a rogue actor will be able to see the password the application uses. If MySQL supports it, you could also set 2-way SSL. Setting up a firewall like you suggested is OK, but you must be shure that the ougoing IP address of your WordPress server does not change...

Comment: Thanks @ixe013. Yes, connection between the servers will be encrypted. I'll look into what methods are available, such as 2-way SSL. Both have a dedicated IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Likely to have too much latency, and thus defeat the purpose of splitting the App and DB onto separate servers (i.e., to get performance gains).**

This depends on how your datacenter handles the traffic. Usually they have routes set up to not let the traffic between two machines in the same datacenter go over an outside router because that would make no sense and just add (as you said) unnecessary latency. You can imagine other customers have similar scenarios.
You can ask your contact at the datacenter but I'm 99% sure that the latency you can expect will be similar to a direct LAN connection. In all my past experience communication between IPs that belonged to the same datacenter never left the datacenter (except if explicitly routed that way by the customers).

**2) Whether this presents any significant security concern. I presume we can set up the firewall on the MySQL server to only allow connections from the IP address of the Application (Wordpress) server. Correct? And that should minimise the security risk.**

It does present a security concern as with any machine with direct internet access. You should definitely set up a firewall on the MySQL-Server and you should definitely not only rely on the Hostname/IP/MAC of the source alone, since Spoofing is still a thing (never assume your provider/datacenter handles these things for you). Which basically means you should always have encryption set up, either in the MySQL connection or in a point to point VPN or (what I would do because I'm paranoid) both, there should NEVER be any kind of unencrypted connection between the two servers of over the public IPs. In that regard, treat the SQL server as if it was on the other side of the world.

Additionally, you can ask your datacenter for support. Most of them offer routing/firewall/ddos-protection solutions in addition to your own, to maybe take off some load.

Comment: Thanks for these insights. Very helpful. I'll look into the VPN approach, combined with encryption. Ixe013 suggests 2-way SSL. No idea what that means exactly, as opposed to standard TLS encryption, but will look into it.

Comment: I've confirmed data between the two servers won't go via an external router. Thanks for that bit of info.